# Build a linux app that uses flutter_libserialport?

Tags: linux, flutter, ubuntu

I'm building a flutter app on macOS, Windows and linux that uses flutter_libserialport.  It builds and runs on macOS and Windows, but doesn't build on Ubuntu linux.  Flutter build linux fails with a message saying that cmake can't build make files, because it lacks a package, though it doesn't specify which package is missing.  I've installed build-essential, lib tool, automake and autoconf, but no joy.  Any insight would be much appreciated.